# How to call webapp post url from angular app

Tags: angularjs, webapp2

Here is my webapp Class

```
class CreateChannel(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        userEmail = self.request.get("userEmail", default_value='')
        userDBId = self.request.get("userId", default_value='')
        logging.info("Deleting existing channel and creating new channle for User Id : " + userDBId)
```

And I am trying like this from angular controller

```
var objUser = JSON.stringify({
            "userId": Session.activeUserId,
            "email": Session.userId
        });

var deferred = $q.defer();
var route = URLS.AppUrl + "/createchannel";
deferred.resolve($http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: route,
            data: objUser
        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log("GeneralService : Channel Created");
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log("error")
        }));
```

I am not able to get the passed parameters. What is the issue ?

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed:

The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

Comment: meaning of status i know. Issue is how can I call this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For json Content-Type, you should do,

```
import json
class CreateChannel(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        params = json.loads(self.request.body)
        userEmail = params.get("userEmail") if params.get("userEmail") else ""
        userDBId = params.get("userId") if params.get("userId") else ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u try something like this:

```
var objUser = {
        "userId": Session.activeUserId,
        "userEmail": Session.userId
    };

var deferred = $q.defer();
var route = URLS.AppUrl + "/createchannel";
deferred.resolve($http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: route,
            data: objUser
        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log("GeneralService : Channel Created");
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log("error")
        }));
```

Your server supports other format, so u have to change your objUser.

Comment: Try to debug, what's comming to your server from angular post request. Names like "userId", "userEmail" should by the same.

Comment: I checked the problem is, it is not getting the parameters

Comment: 405 status was due to some other code. the real problem is I am not able to get the passed parameters